# is fracking inherently more contaminating than extracting or transporting crude oil, coal and non-fracking natural gas?

Tags: fracking

I keep reading about fracking and cases of contaminated water supplies. I would like to know if there is quantitative evidence of fracking being more disruptive to people's lives in the areas of extraction, compared to crude oil, coal and non-fracking natural gas.

For example, are there more cases of fracking-related contaminated water supplies than crude oil extraction? Coal?

Comment: "other sources" is *incredibly broad*.

Comment: Related: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34878/has-fracking-caused-tap-water-to-become-flammable/38728#38728 and https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/2463/1044